# how to remove this warnings in beeline commands :Hive3 namespace found Warning: HADOOP_YARN_HOME is invalid

Tags: hadoop, hive, beeline

when i use beeline (hive 3 client) i get this warning , using Hive 3 in Ubuntu 16.04:

```
Hive3 namespace found
Warning: HADOOP_YARN_HOME is invalid
Warning: HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME is invalid
Warning: HADOOP_YARN_HOME is invalid
Warning: HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME is invalid
Warning: HADOOP_YARN_HOME is invalid
Warning: HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME is invalid
```

which also shown in output files for commands like :

```
beeline --silent=true --outputformat=csv2  -f local_queries_path.hql >  local_output_path.csv
```

how do i remove this warnings ?

Answer (score 0):

@juniorsoftware

You need to set the ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLES (HADOOP_YARN_HOME & HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME_ to make the warnings go away.  There are many different ways to do this in your ssh user profile or by manually executing the commands, etc.

Comment: how should i know what path to use on them ? where are they usually located in Hive client Ubuntu 16.04 vm ?